# Debug code to assign the sum with the total of one item with other

Tags: python

Im a student and this is my first experience with Python so I'm having a little trouble. The electronic workbook I'm using, Zybooks is doing a horrible job of explaining (or lack thereof) how to go about doing what it's asking. The entire lesson does not once talk about how to write this specific type of code.

It asks...

Write a statement that assigns total_coins with the sum of nickel_count and dime_count. Sample output for 100 nickels and 200 dimes is:

```
total_coins = 0
nickel_count = int(input())
dime_count = int(input())
print(total_coins)
```

I have no idea where to begin.

I tried:

```
print(nickel_count + dime_count)
```

I get the correct answer (300) but it creates a second line with just a zero so it marks it as wrong. I just need the 300 by itself.

300
0

Comment: I think you're confusing code that was provided with the question for "sample output".  Start by running that code -- you should see it prompt you for two values, and then print `0`.  What needs to change for it to print the sum of the two values you entered?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) For debugging help, You need to provide example input, desired output, and actual output (i.e. error message). I'm not familiar with Zybooks, so I don't know how I would test this code myself, in order to help you. Please also use a descriptive title, since SO is not a Zybooks support site. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: Thank you. wjandrea

Comment: @jemcmorrow Happy to help! Your edits are a great improvement, but it's not clear where the 0 is coming from. Are you sure that's your complete code? Maybe you have an extra `print(total_coins)` below.

Comment: @wjandrea,  Python Programmer 1's solution worked. I was entering "print(nickel_count + dime_count)" when I should have been entering "total_coins = nickel_count + dime_count". I wasn't sure where the zero was coming from either. It's a simulated environment so that could be the reason why too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start, we need to use your code and adapt it to set `total coins` to the number (`dime_count` + `nickel_count`). This is very simple:

```
nickel_count = int(input())
dime_count = int(input())

total_coins = nickel_count + dime_count
print(total_coins)
```

Also, to make it clearer for whoever you are doing the challenge for, add a prompt to the `input` function.

```
nickel_count = int(input('How many nickels have you got? '))
dime_count = int(input('How many dimes have you got? '))

total_coins = nickel_count + dime_count
print(total_coins)
```

**Done!**

Comment: Not sure I understand
When I enter...

print(nickel_count + dime_count)

I get the correct answer but it has a zero on the next line so it's marking it as wrong

300
0

Comment: @jemcmorrow     If you have typed the answer in as a `string`, it simply joins them together. I would like to thank @Asocia for reminding me to put the `int()` function around it. This adds the numbers together rather than adding the `strings`. A `string` is letters rather than numbers.